# How can I re generate a new JPA entity(and a database table in a different database schema) for an existing jhipster project?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jhipster

How can I generate an entity(and a database table) in a different schema other than the default public schema for an existing Jhipster(4.6.2) project generated with spring boot and AngularJS as the technology stack. [Database - Postgresql]

Answer (score 0):

I am very interested if it is possible. Otherwise one simple way to reach that: you could try to generate the entity using the jhipster command `jhipster entity <entityName> --[options]` [see](https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/) for more details.

And customize your application to use multiple databases by following this excellent article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases